# Goreleaser did not find GITHUB_TOKEN

Tags: github, github-actions, goreleaser

I have a [project](https://github.com/fabelx/go-solc-select) and I'm trying to set up [goreleaser](https://goreleaser.com/) using [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions). But I'm getting an error:

```
GoReleaser latest installed successfully v0.1.0 tag found for commit '96480db'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/goreleaser-action/1.10.2/x64/goreleaser release --rm-dist
  •starting release...
  • loading config file                              file=.goreleaser.yml
  ⨯release failed after 0serror=yaml: line 26: did not find expected key

Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/goreleaser-action/1.10.2/x64/goreleaser' failed with exit code 1
```

**.goreleaser.yml**

```
before:
  hooks:
    - go mod tidy

builds:

  - main: cmd/gsolc-select/main.go
    binary: gsolc-select
    id: gsolc-select-cli

    env:
      - CGO_ENABLED=0

    goos: [ windows,linux,darwin ]
    goarch: [ amd64,386,arm,arm64 ]
    ignore:
      - goos: darwin
        goarch: 386
      - goos: windows
        goarch: arm
      - goos: windows
        goarch: arm64

    flags:
      - -trimpath

  - main: cmd/solc/main.go
    binary: solc
    id: solc

    env:
      - CGO_ENABLED=0

    goos: [ windows,linux,darwin ]
      goarch: [ amd64,386,arm,arm64 ]
      ignore:
        - goos: darwin
          goarch: 386
        - goos: windows
          goarch: arm
        - goos: windows
          goarch: arm64

archives:
  - format: zip
    id: gsolc-select
    builds: [ gsolc-select-cli ]
    replacements:
      darwin: macOS

  - format: zip
      id: solc
      builds: [ solc ]
      replacements:
        darwin: macOS

checksum:
  algorithm: sha256
```

**.github/workflows/release.yml**

```
name:  Release Binary

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - "v*"
jobs:
  release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - uses: actions/setup-go@v3
        with:
          go-version: 1.18

      - uses: goreleaser/goreleaser-action@v3
        with:
          args: "release --rm-dist"
          version: latest
          workdir: .
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
```

As I understand it, the github itself provides the **secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN** value. I tried through ***settings*** -> ***secrets*** -> add a custom token (environment variable), but the error was the same. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: In the action logs, where `goreleaser` is called, you can see what is pass as `env`.

Comment: Everything seems to be fine with **secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN** and I misinterpreted the error. I tried to change the position of the line **GITHUB_TOKEN : "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"** (line 26) in the **.github/workflows/release.yml** file, but the error still pointed to the 26th line. As I understand it, I misconfigured the **.goreleaser.yml** file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `gorelease.yml` file has different indentations problems.

I'm not familiar with GoReleaser, and the error message isn't helping, but using tools like:

- http://www.yamllint.com/ (this one reproduces the same error message when validating the file: *error=yaml: line 26: did not find expected key*)

  - *Note that the `goreleaser check` also returns that message.*
- https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-validator (this one pointed out the indentation error)
- https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator (this one also pointed out the indentation error)

I observed that this block:

```
    goos: [ windows,linux,darwin ]
      goarch: [ amd64,386,arm,arm64 ]
      ignore:
        - goos: darwin
          goarch: 386
        - goos: windows
          goarch: arm
        - goos: windows
          goarch: arm64
```

Should instead be like this:

```
    goos: [ windows,linux,darwin ]
    goarch: [ amd64,386,arm,arm64 ]
    ignore:
      - goos: darwin
        goarch: 386
      - goos: windows
        goarch: arm
      - goos: windows
        goarch: arm64
```

---

And this other block:

```
  - format: zip
      id: solc
      builds: [ solc ]
      replacements:
        darwin: macOS
```

Should instead be like this:

```
  - format: zip
    id: solc
    builds: [ solc ]
    replacements:
      darwin: macOS
```

Correcting the indentation should resolve the problem. Moreover, as it doesn't seem to be related to the Github Actions workflow configurations, it should allow the workflow to run as expected.